# What other equipment or hardwares I should buy along with raspberry pi

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, hardware

I am planning to build some primary level of project like home made robot, which I need to explore an image recognition and path recognition(using four wheels vehicle). So I am looking to buy a device like Raspberry pi.

What other equipment or hardwares I should buy along with raspberry pi.

Which one is better Arduino or raspberry pi for robotics using AI.

Comment: I tried to answer your question, but it would be helpful if you provided more specifics about your application.  I wanted to avoid a laundry-list of parts, and instead focused on your second question: the differences between the Arduino and the Pi.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* user9219405, but I'm afraid that *[shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)* really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works, and the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) for details of how to write a good question.

Answer (score 3):

First, it is important to understand the differences between the Arduino and the Raspberry Pi.  You can read more [here](https://makezine.com/2015/12/04/admittedly-simplistic-guide-raspberry-pi-vs-arduino/) and [here](https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/arduino-vs-raspberry-pi/).

- The **Arduino** is a [microcontroller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcontroller).  It is a specialized board that handles low level, often repetitive tasks like reading a sensor or controlling a motor with a motor driver.
- The **Raspberry Pi** is a complete Linux computer that typically runs on the Raspbian OS.  While the Raspberry Pi has a set of GPIO ports that can interface with sensors and motor drivers, the Pi can also process higher level tasks.  The Pi is capable of running python and C/C++ libraries such as OpenCV and other AI frameworks.

Using the two boards in a project are not mutually exclusive!  You can use the Arduino for controlling motors and processing sensors while using the Raspberry Pi for your AI libraries and decision making steps.